# change ContentTitle text proprities without making a custom notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-mediaplayer, custom-notification

I'm trying to make a notification with MediaStyle without creating a custom notification myself.

so far I got everything to work but since some of my users use Arabic the contentTitle is aligned to the right and I'd like it to be to the left.

How would I do that without making a new custom notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the RLT Unicode which worked great.